# Throwing Error/Exception when an unnecessary Argument is sent in PHP

Tags: php, arguments, limiting

Suppose this:
Wrking with arguments (or not) in PHP.

```
Class myclass {
  function noArgument() {
    echo "no arguments<br>";
  }
  function oneArgument($one) {
    echo "the only argument is ".$one."<br>";
  }
  function twoArgument($one,$two) {
    echo "the first argument is ".$one." the second is ".$two."<br>";
  }
}
```

Now, I show you my test of my previous class.

```
$TestMyClass = new myclass();

echo "<br>Omiting arguments<br>";
$TestMyClass->twoArgument("*Lack one*");
$TestMyClass->oneArgument();

echo "<br>Excess arguments<br>";
$TestMyClass->noArgument("*With Argument*");
$TestMyClass->oneArgument("*First Argument*", "*Second Argument*");

echo "<br>End Test<br>";
```

**Result**

```
Omiting arguments

Warning: Missing argument 2 for myclass::twoArgument(), called in C:\...\test.php on line 4 and defined in C:\...\test.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined variable: two in C:\...\test.php on line 19
the first argument is *Lack one* the second is

Warning: Missing argument 1 for myclass::oneArgument(), called in C:\...\test.php on line 5 and defined in C:\...\test.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: one in C:\...\test.php on line 16
the only argument is

Excess arguments
no arguments
the only argument is *First Argument*

End Test
```

I need a similar treatment with the excess arguments!
I need to raise error (**or limit the number of arguments**) when use unnecessary arguments too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`func_num_args()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) to check how many arguments are being passed and throw an `Exception` if there are too many.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [func_num_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) that is used to show how many arguments a function received.

This short sample should give you an idea of how you can implement it:

```
function testfunc($arg1, $arg2)
{
    if (func_num_args() > 2)
    { 
        echo "Error!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Arg1 => $arg1, Arg2 => $arg2";
    }
}

testfunc(1,2,3,4);
```

Outputs:

```
Error!
```

A call of

```
testfunc(1,2)
```

Outputs:

```
Arg1 => 1, Arg2 => 2
```